# Evaluate bivariate normal distribution with Gauss-Hermite quadrature

Tags: r, integral

By using the `library(statmod)`, I can evaluate a univariate normal distribution using Gauss-Hermite quadrature. But how can I evaluate a bivariate normal distribution using Gauss-Hermite quadrature?

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

I have given the codes that I used for evaluating univariate normal using Gauss-Hermite 5 points. But how I can I do for bivariate normal distribution?

```
library(statmod)
## generating Gauss-Hermite quadrature points and weights
q=gauss.quad(n=5,kind="hermite")

## defining univariate normal function
mu=0
sigma=2
norm=function(b){
    M=((2*pi*sigma)^(-1/2))*exp(-(1/2)*(b^2/sigma^2))
    return(M)
}

## approximating the integral of norm(b) using Gauss-Hermite method
sum(q$weights*norm(q$nodes)*exp(q$nodes^2))
```

Comment: Relevant: [A note on multivariate Gauss-Hermite quadrature](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/0e39/32b776eb3803e0f0ae2e414f69399daa411d.pdf); also worth checking out is the vignette to [mvQuad](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mvQuad/vignettes/mvQuad_intro.html) which *"[p]rovides methods to construct multivariate grids, which can be used for multivariate quadrature"*.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a minimal worked-through example, based on a bivariate standard normal (probability) density with a given covariance matrix `sigma` and the quadrature rules implemented in the `mvQuad` library.

Note that we use the Gauss-Legendre quadrature rule, which allows integration over an arbitrary bounded domain because in the Gauss-Hermite quadrature the domain is unbounded from `(-∞, +∞)`. Since we're working with a bivariate standard normal *probability density*, the integral over the unbounded domain trivially equals 1. Generally, `mvQuad::createNIGrid` allows the implementation of various quadrature rules, including the Gauss-Hermite quadrature (see `?createNIGrid` for details).

1. Define a covariance matrix for the a bivariate standard normal probability density

   ```
   library(mvtnorm)
   sigma <- matrix(c(1, 0.2, 0.2, 1), ncol = 2)
   dens <- function(x) dmvnorm(x, sigma = sigma)
   ```

   We are interested in the integral of `dens` in the domain `x ϵ [-1, 2]` and `y ϵ [-1, 2]`.
2. We follow instructions from the [mvQuad vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mvQuad/vignettes/mvQuad_intro.html) to create a grid and rescale to the domain of interest

   ```
   library(mvQuad)
   grid <- createNIGrid(dim = 2, type = "GLe", level = 6)
   rescale(grid, domain = rbind(c(-1, 2), c(-1, 2)))
   ```
3. Calculate the integral of the bivariate normal in the domain `x ϵ [-1, 2]` and `y ϵ [-1, 2]`

   ```
   quadrature(function(x) dmvnorm(x, sigma = sigma), grid = grid)
   #[1] 0.6796583
   ```
4. This value is in good agreement with the value from `pmvnorm` (which computes the distribution function of the multivariate normal for arbitrary limits and covariance matrices)

   ```
   pmvnorm(lower = c(-1, -1), upper = c(2, 2), sigma = sigma)
   #[1] 0.6796584
   #attr(,"error")
   #[1] 1e-15
   #attr(,"msg")
   #[1] "Normal Completion"
   ```

Comment: You're very welcome @Mohammad; please consider closing the question by setting the green checkmark next to the answer. That way you help keeping SO tidy and make it easier for future SO users to identify relevant questions & answers. You probably should do that for your older questions as well. Thanks.